# "Error: CRM.url called before initialization" on contribution page

Tags: profile, contribution-page, addresses

I am getting this - "Error: CRM.url called before initialization"
when I select the country from 'country field' included in the profile.

Steps to replicate:

> - Created a profile including address fields street, pincode, country, states, city
> - created a contribution page.
> - added profile for that contribution page.
> - Opened "contribution link" for live mode.
> - Try to change the country name state/province field keep spinning.

[image]

What will be the issue?

reference file:civicrm/js/crm.ajax.js

Comment: Make sure js files are loaded before the page load. Try changing the theme to default and confirm if you still see the issue

Comment: Yes, @jitendra-fuzion...  I have just checked this possibility. Basically, this error title is mentioned in the file - civicrm/js/crm.ajax.js. 

The common.js and crm.ajax.js is loaded inside <head> tag. I have just checked this by doing view source.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this annoying error after installing webform_civicrm on Drupal 9 and testing a donation.

It was simply a case of running the `cv flush` command followed by `drush cr`

Hope this helps!